# c++ fstream::read only returning 1st char

Tags: c++, fstream, bmp

**Preface:** I am a inexperienced coder so its probably an obvious error. Also like all of this code is stolen and slapped together so I claim no ownership of this code.

**System:** I am using windows 10 64 bit. I write my code in Notepad++ and compile with MinGW G++.

**What I'm trying to do:** I am trying to read an entire file (BMP format) into a variable and return a pointer to that variable as the return of a function.

**What's happening:** The variable is only storing the first char of the file.

```
char* raw_data(std::string filename){
//100% non-stolen
    std::ifstream is (filename, std::ifstream::binary);
    if (is) {
        // get length of file:
        is.seekg (0, is.end);
        int length = is.tellg();
        is.seekg (0, is.beg);
        std::cout << is.tellg() << "\n"; 
        
        char * buffer = new char [length];
        std::cout << "Reading " << length << " characters... \n";
        // read data as a block:
        is.read (buffer,length);
        std::cout << "\n\n" << *buffer << "\n\n";
    
        if (is)
            {std::cout << "all characters read successfully.";}
        else
            {std::cout << "error: only " << is.gcount() << " could be read";}
        is.close();
        // ...buffer contains the entire file...
//101% non-stolen
        return {buffer};
    }
    return {};
}
```

The code calling the function is

```
char * image_data = new char [image_size];
        image_data = raw_data("Bitmap.bmp");
```

This compiles fine and the EXE outputs

```
0
Reading 2665949 characters...


B

all characters read successfully.
```

The file **Bitmap.bmp** starts:

```
BM¶ƒ     6   (   €  ‰        €ƒ Δ  Δ          ¨δό¨δό¨δό¨
```

As you can see, the variable **buffer** only stores the first char of **Bitmap.bmp** (if I change the 1st char it also changes)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Remember that C-style strings are really called ***null-terminated** strings*. The *null-terminator* is the byte `0`. A raw binary file cont contain plenty of `0` bytes. You can't treat raw binary data as strings.

Comment: On another note, you have a memory leak. What happens with the pointer originally assigned to `image_data` once you reassign that variable?

Comment: Besides, `*buffer` is exactly the same as `buffer[0]`. So inside the function you print only the first "character" of `buffer`.

Comment: To solve the two first problems, I would recommend you use a `std::vector<std::byte>` (or `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` if you don't have `std::byte`) as container for the data. First of all it won't be easily treated as a "string", secondly it have automatic handling of memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cpp
std::cout << "\n\n" << *buffer << "\n\n";
```

Buffer is a `char*`, so by dereferencing it you get a single `char`, which in your case is B. If you want to output the whole data that you read just don't dereference the pointer, in C/C++ `char*` has special treatment when outputing with `std::cout`,`printf` and such.

```cpp
std::cout << "\n\n" << buffer << "\n\n";
```

Keep in mind that by convention, C-strings in `char*` should be null-terminated, yours is not and the caller of your function has no effective way to check how long it is, that information is lost as functions like `strlen` expect the Cstring to be null-terminated too. You should look at `std::vector<char>` or `std::string` for holding such data, as they will hold the information about the size, and clean after themselves.

Comment: Using iostream to output buffer will be rather meaningless due to nul-bytes in the binary file. Better to loop outputting the `unsigned char` hex value of each byte (or at least a headers worth [BMP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format))